# How can I get a HTML button to pass a form`s string through a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following form and button:

home.html

```
<input class="draft" type="text" id="message" placeholder="Write your msg here!"/> 
<button class="send">Send</button>
```

And I need the string that will be filled in the form to be passed on to the `Chat.send()` function below as an argument:

Applications.js

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  Chat.send();
})
```

How do I tie the two together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  Chat.send($('#message').val());
});
```

Assuming you add the `id="button"` to your button, otherwise use a selector like `button.send`

Comment: `#button` is incorrect selector (unless @kikomello will add `id="button"`).

Comment: @ShayNissel Indeed, I failed to notice that! I've updated the answer accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

```
$("button.send").click(function(){
    var text = $("input#message").val();
    Chat.send(text);
});
```